Android Studio Emulator not starting Windows 11
I have freshly installed windows 11 and installed android studio ladybug version and tried to open the android emulator but it shows error 
And I further dig up on the log in the android studio to find the problem. And here is the log. If anyone can tell me what is going wrong here and possible fix please. Here is the log:
2024-11-18 09:03:47,238 [ 637371]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.progress.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Errors during XML parse:
2024-11-18 09:03:47,238 [ 637371]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.progress.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
2024-11-18 09:03:53,406 [ 643539]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 34 - C:\Users\geniusAlada\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_7_Pro_API_34
2024-11-18 09:03:53,422 [ 643555]   WARN - #c.i.u.j.JBCefApp - JCefAppConfig.class is not from a JBR module, url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/lib/lib.jar!/com/jetbrains/cef/JCefAppConfig.class (Use JBR bundled with the IDE)
2024-11-18 09:03:53,531 [ 643664]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 34 - Android emulator version 35.2.10.0 (build_id 12414864) (CL:N/A)
2024-11-18 09:03:53,531 [ 643664]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 34 - Graphics backend: gfxstream
2024-11-18 09:03:53,531 [ 643664]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 34 - Found systemPath C:\Users\geniusAlada\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\
2024-11-18 09:03:54,318 [ 644451]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
2024-11-18 09:03:54,318 [ 644451]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 34 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
2024-11-18 09:03:54,412 [ 644545]   WARN - #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.DeviceAction - The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7_Pro_API_34 has terminated.
com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7_Pro_API_34 has terminated.
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport$executeOnPooledThread$1.run(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:134)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextCallable.call(ContextCallable.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:27)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2024-11-18 09:03:59,185 [ 649318]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-11-18 09:03:59,185 [ 649318]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-11-18 09:03:59,276 [ 649409]   INFO - #c.i.a.o.PathMacrosImpl - Saved path macros: {}
2024-11-18 09:03:59,292 [ 649425]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appCodeInsightSettings took 16 ms, DaemonCodeAnalyzerSettings took 20 ms, FileTypeManager took 16 ms, TextDiff


I think the main issue which you need to fix is :
Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 34 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
Which states that the is issue related to graphic driver or try to re install the Microsoft Visual C++ or try to update the graphic drivers manually.
Also , please ensure you check the virtualization in your BIOS setting as when I started in android studio , I also faced a similar issue related to this.
Thank You.
